# Quickly/Glade autoadjust text position

Tags: ubuntu, pygtk, glade, canonical-quickly

In Quickly/Glade, is it possible to keep the text (well, labels) centered, so when I maximize my program's window, the text stays centered? It's probably something easy to do, but I have been unable to find where to auto-adjust the position. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I was also referred here from Askubuntu, so I hope this is the right place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the packing properties of the labels (or perhaps the labels' container, if it's a `VBox` for example) and make sure that `expand` is `True` and `fill` is also `True`.

Comment: It was that, and the fact that I had a fixed Window. Thanks for your help :D